# How can I access the SMS messages in a Windows Mobile device

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, embedded, pocketpc

I'm searching for a code that will alow access to the SMS messages stored in a Pocket PC device with Windows Mobile so I can download/backup them to a Windows PC.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might start by looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839381.aspx), on how to build SMS enabled applications that expose the API's for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use COM, the code isn't super short, but someone has written a wrapper for it

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/PocketPCandSmartphone.aspx

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mapidotnet

Or if you have a budget
http://inthehand.com/content/Mobile.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Never played with it, but assembly Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.dll contains classes SmsAccount and SmsMessage. Look at [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this namespace: [Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.MessageInterception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.messageinterception.aspx)

Focus on MessageInterceptor class and its MessageReceived event. MessageCondition too.